# Complex layout in Jetpack Compose with nested scrolling composables

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn

The idea is to create a layout similar to this pseudo-code in jetpack compose :

```
<SwipeRefreshLayout>
 <CoordinatorLayout>
  <NavigationDrawer>
  <AppBarLayout>
   <CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    <ConstraintLayout/> (contains some text view)
   </CollapsingToolbarLayout>
  <AppBarLayout>
  <NestedScrollView>
   <LinearLayout>
    <ConstraintLayout> (contains some text views and buttons)
    <HorizontalRecyclerView/>
    <TabLayout/> (which works like sticky header)
    <ViewPager/>
   </LinearLayout>
  </NestedScrollView>
 </CoordinatorLayout>
</SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

The problem I'm facing is that LazyColumn cant go inside other scrolling components. So if you could guide me to some concepts/links/samples that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use

```
FlowColumn {
//
}
```

guide
https://google.github.io/accompanist/flowlayout/